# Graphviz: Edge orientation to and from same node

Tags: graphviz, edges, arrows

I'm creating some multilevel SEM graphs and I'm running into a small problem.  The latent variable at the bottom of the graph (labeled "WF") is supposed to have a double-headed edge to and from it but the edge should go under the node.  Note the correct orientation of the topmost node.  Seems and easy fix but I can find it.  Thanks in advance.  (BTW, I've provided only a snippet of the original model, but this is sufficient for the purpose.)

```
digraph stackex {

    {rank=min;
    bf [shape=ellipse]
    bf:nw -> bf:ne [dir = both]}

    {node[shape=square]
      bf -> i1 
      i1[label=X1]
      i1 -> wf [dir=back]}

    {wf [shape=ellipse]
    wf:sw -> wf:se [dir = both]}
}
```

And here's what it produces:

[image: Graphviz Plot]

The double-headed arrow should go under the node labled "WF".

Answer (score 0):

Based on experimentation, it appears that the only way to get

```
wf:sw -> wf:se [dir = both]
```

to do what you want is to add

```
graph [rankdir=TB]
```

Unfortunately, **rankdir** affects the entire graph (not just a subgraph or cluster).  So you can fix one loop, but you break the other.
The only way I've found to accomplish your goal is to hand-modify the **pos** of the offending edge (spline).  This:

```
digraph stackex {
    graph [bb="0,0,82.583,216"];
    node [label="\N",
        shape=square
    ];
    bf  [height=0.5,
        pos="41.292,162",
        shape=ellipse,
        width=0.75];
    bf:nw -> bf:ne  [dir=both,
        pos="s,26.292,177 e,56.292,177 22.277,186.17 18.135,200.16 21.792,216 41.292,216 60.792,216 64.448,200.16 60.306,186.17"];
    i1  [height=0.5,
        label=X1,
        pos="41.292,90",
        width=0.5];
    bf -> i1    [pos="e,41.292,108.1 41.292,143.7 41.292,135.98 41.292,126.71 41.292,118.11"];
    wf  [height=0.5,
        pos="41.292,18",
        shape=ellipse,
        width=0.75];
    i1 -> wf    [dir=back,
        pos="s,41.292,71.697 41.292,61.665 41.292,53.054 41.292,43.791 41.292,36.104"];
    wf:se -> wf:sw  [dir=both,
        pos="s,56.292,3 e,26.292,3 
65.002,8.3185 
92.908,0.389 
88.823,-20 
41.292,-20 
-6.2395,-20 
-10.324,0.389 
17.582,8.3185"];
}
```

And this command
**neato -n2 -Tpng doubleheaded3.fixed.dot >doubleheaded3.fixed.png**
Gives this:
[image]

All in all, I'd suggest the **pic/gpic/dpic** language.  Lower-level, but probably easier to use in the long run.

Comment: Thanks!  That solution required a fair amount of effort, I'm sure.  I'll look into gpic but the nice thing about graphviz is that it works (mostly) pretty well in R and Rmarkdown via the "diagrammeR" package.